# Want to add an LCD display screen for the output motor

Tags: arduino-uno

I want add an LCD display screen at output motor. When the motor runs the LCD display show like "motor 1 run forward" and "motor 1 run reverse". I want it display for all motor but I don't know how code using arduino using 16x2 LCD display screen.

```
int motor_forward1 = 7;
int motor_reverse1 = 6;
int motor_forward2 = 5;
int motor_reverse2 = 4;
int motor_forward3 = 3;
int motor_reverse3 = 2;
int sensor1 = 13;
int sensor2 = 12;

 void setup() 
{

   pinMode(motor_forward1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_forward2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_forward3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(sensor1, INPUT);
   pinMode(sensor2, INPUT);
 }

 void loop()
 {
   if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH)
   {
     print
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,1);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   else if (digitalRead(12) == HIGH)
   {
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,1); 
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   else
   {
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,1); 
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   delay(5000);
 }
```

Comment: Other than the LiquidCrystal library?

Answer (score 1):

From this [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-A-16x2-LCD-Display-To-An-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS):

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print(" **Text for line 1 of LCD**");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(" **Text for line 2 of LCD**");
  // THE REST OF YOUR SETUP
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH) {
        // I assume this is the motor going forward
        lcd.print("motor 1 run forward");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Install" is a bit facetious though, since it comes with the IDE these days.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that :)

Comment: @circuitBurn Thanks for your code. But I have used arduino pin 5,4,3 and 2. need connect parallel to LCD screen?